# Define uri cell with text

Tags: uri, cell, backgrid

I need to print an anchor in column cell. But, I don't have idea as how do it correctly.

**I defined the cell as:**

```
{name: 'menu', label: 'Menu', cell: Backgrid.UriCell.extend(), sortable: false}
```

But, I don't know how set the text of the link.
Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

With standard uri cell, you can't have text of the link different from actual uri. You'll need to override render() method in order to accomplish that.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the [source code](https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid/blob/master/src/cell.js#L375). It's very simple.